# How to select the items in form helper

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I want to know how to use form helper deeply

Given, there is a table like this

```
ID |student |sex
1  | bob    | 2
2  | kayo   | 1 
3  | ken    | 2


protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
       ->add('student')
```

this code shows
shows select box

```
<option> bob</option>
<option> kayo</option>
<option> ken</option>
```

But I want to show only candidate whose sex is 2

```
<option> bob</option>
<option> ken</option>
```

How can I do this?

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not use SonataAdminBundle but I think you can do it like that cause it using Symfony [entity type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#query-builder) so your code should looks like:

```
$formMapper
   ->add(
       'student',
       'entity',
       array(
           'query_builder' => function (\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $rep) {
                return $rep
                    ->createQueryBuilder('s')
                    ->where('s.sex = 2')
                ;
           }
       )
   )
;
```

Comment: Thanks!l310!! I have changed 'entity' -> 'null' because it shows the class is missing error.my final code is.

            ->add('student',
                    null,
                        array(
                       'query_builder' => function (\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $rep) {
                            return $rep
                                ->createQueryBuilder('s')
                                ->where('s.sex = 1');
                        }
                    )
                 )

Comment: thanks l310. I really appreciate your help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135722/how-to-select-the-items-which-belonging-to-group-in-form-helper However I bumped into new issue,I made another question.Please have a look if you have time.